# UK visa refusal because of system mistake and my bank statement

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, ghanaian-citizens

[image]

1. ECO said I didn't provide a holiday plan but that's not true, I provided 10 days detailed itinerary.
2. This must of have been a system mistake because I chose Ghs currency but some how 2 of the stated amount were in GBP. I earn Ghs5000 a month, my monthly expenditure is Ghs 1500, and my intended money to spend in the UK was Ghs 10,000. But I don't understand how my application showed GBP. That doesn't make any sense( why would I state my monthly income as Ghs 5000 and say my monthly expenditure is GBP 1500 which is almost Ghs10,000 when converted, that's twice my earning.)
3. Regarding my bank statement, I'm currently running my family business. I'm a timber expoter( I provided all my company certs and licenses) sometimes i sell some of my containers in Ghana and I let my buyers send money directly to my personal account thus resulting with the regular transactions/credit.  I even provided my company's bank statement.

How do I explain this to them and how do I prove source of funds so that my next application will not be refused again?

Comment: You can address 1 & 2 in your next application by checking the input carefully before submitting, and explaining further in the section at the end of the application and/or a covering letter. Re 3 - Typically, invoices, tax returns and trading accounts (profit & loss, balance sheet) would suffice. Credits to your personal account purporting to be from business transactions with no supporting evidence won’t do. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: I’m sure you still have the pdf. Can you check if it says GBP where you think it should say GHS?

Comment: The instructions by Traveler are informative, support as many of your bank transactions as possible with documentation. They view different random incoming funds very suspiciously without realizing a businessman routinely has such cash flows. Also note that Ghana is one country which has a high rate of absconders so the British Visa Officers are sometimes quick to deny. In your case however the mistake in the currency thing alone was fatal. Fix those errors and reapply however do not bee too hopeful. These visa decisions are sometimes strange.

Comment: @Hanky Penny, yes it does, and I tried reapplying again to see if the same thing will happen but it did. I have sent them an email to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately system errors such as those you witnessed can happen. To minimise the risk of these happening again in the future, the best thing you can do is double check all the information you input, before submitting the application. In addition, you can use the section at the end of the application and/or a covering letter to provide further details on the information you submit. This will help you solve points 1) and 2).

Point 3) is the crucial one. The purpose of bank statements is [to demonstrate that you lead a stable life, and that you can support yourself during your stay in the UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab). There are several money flow patterns which are likely to trigger red flags. Typically, an account showing irregular incoming cash flows is likely to be construed as funds parking, as well as demonstrating an erratic/unstable lifestyle. Unfortunately, as you point out, your job as an import/export businessman, inherently causes you to have irregular cash flows in your accounts. This is nothing to be worried about, as long as you can explain the reasons for such erratic deposists, and the provenance of the funds. To do this you can provide a list of documents, including but not limited to:

- personal and company bank statements
- invoices
- tax returns
- trading accounts
- profit & loss,
- balance sheets

The more valid supporting information you provide, the easier it is for the immigration officer to make a decision on your application.